# How to resolve HTTP Status 406 in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am beginner and trying to create REST api using spring MVC but I am getting HTTP 406 error. I dont know whats went wrong in code. Here is my controller.

RestController.Java

```
 package com.nitish.sample;
    @RestController
    public class LoginRESTController {

    @Autowired
    public LoginService loginService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/login",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}) 
    public List<Login> authentication(){        
        List<Login> login = loginService.getUser();     
        return login;
    }}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For more clarification I am adding dispachet servlet and web.xml
HelloWebSpring-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.nitish.sample" />   

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <!-- <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/> -->
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWebSpring</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWebSpring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWebSpring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

Here is the server snap

[image: API request]

Comment: try to remove headers="Accept=*/*" in your @RequestMapping

Comment: A RestController by default will produce json response, so you don't need the
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}

Additionally, remove the headers="Accept=*/*" from the annotation and give it a try. Also please check if you have @EnableWebMvc added to your dispatcher/servlet/mvc configuration.

Comment: *note: if you use @ RestController in your class, all methods in class is default @ ResponseBody and you don't need to add it.

Comment: @Stefan I have remove header="Accept=*/* and produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} but still facing issue. Also I have not added EnableWebMvc in my dispachter/servlet config.

Comment: @TrầnQuốcVũ I have remove header="Accept=*/* but still facing issue.

Comment: @NitishPatel Did you try send request from postman?

Comment: @TrầnQuốcVũ please add EnableWebMvc to your configuration.

Comment: you actually shoud wrap this to an ResponseEntity. So do something like this:

Comment: @TrầnQuốcVũ I am not sending request from postman.I am using default eclipse browser.

Comment: @Stefan After adding EnableWebMvc  it gives the annotation EnableWebMvc is disallowed for this location compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally you should try to wrap this into an ResponseEntity. I would do it this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/login",method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ResponseEntity<?> authentication(){        
    List<Login> login = loginService.getUser();     
    return new ResponseEntity<>(login, HttpStatus.OK);
}}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: I have tried with your code but still getting HTTP 406. For better understanding I have uploaded my dispatcher-servlet and web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible solutions I would give a try with :

1. As you are using @RestController so it provides @ResponseBody internally so you don't have to use it so remove @ResponseBody annotation.
2. Try removing accept and produces attributes also as rest controller content type is JSON itself.
3. Also if you are making request using postman or any rest client then make sure that you add content type in headers.

Hope it helps..!

Comment: as per your comment I have remove @ResponseBody and I am making request using postman or any rest client. I m just making request from my eclipse IDE browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove headers="Accept=*/*" .
2. In your HelloWebSpring-Servlet.xml add **mvc:annotation-driven** .

This will make spring configure your @RestController.

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.nitish.sample" />   

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <!-- <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/> -->
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>


</beans>
```

mvc:annotation-driven Details : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config

Comment: I have added below code in my dispatcher.xml

    <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
 <!-- Bind the return value of the Rest service to the ResponseBody. -->
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
   <util:list id="beanList">
    <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
   </util:list>
  </property>
 </bean>
It works for me.

Comment: adding mvc:annotation-driven to you dispatcher should automatically do what you have done. Whatever you did is absolutely correct but mvc:annotation-driven does some more default sensible configuration for you as the document suggest. It will also help you in upgrading spring version as AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is deprecated since spring 3.2 .